# How do I fix the .info Method in yfinance?

Tags: python, yfinance

I am trying to learn yfinance in Python. I covered several modules but for some reason the .info method stopped working. It was returning results last week, but suddenly stopped.

```
   import yfinance as yf
   import pandas as pd
   data = yf.download("AMZN AAPL GOOG", start="2017-01-01",
                end="2017-04-30", group_by='tickers')

   data
   aapl = yf.Ticker("aapl")
   aapl.info['forwardPE']
```

Any help is really appreciated